# M2_HOME on mac for Intellij

Tags: java, macos, maven, environment-variables

I am using Mac OS X Yosemite and Intellij Idea 14.0.3

I have set M2_HOME in /etc/launchd.conf as well as environment.plist. Neither of them seems to be taken into consideration by Intellij. What am i missing here?

Comment: Did you restart after setting M2_HOME?

Comment: Maybe [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053666/maven-home-m2-home-not-being-picked-up-by-intellij-idea)

Comment: Or [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8221587/intellij-cant-find-my-m2-home-why-is-that) or [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27529332/m2-home-not-working-in-intellij-on-osx-10-10-1-yosemite) or [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933114/how-to-run-intellij-and-maven-on-os-x/5132547#5132547)

Comment: Why do you think that you need to set M2_HOME at all?

Answer (score 1):

You may try to set M2_HOME from your InterlIJ.

**1.** Go IntelliJ IDEA > Preferences > IDE Settings > Path Variables. Show here your M2_HOME manually.
**2.** Restart your IDE
**3.** IntelliJ IDEA > Preferences >Project Settings > Maven > Maven home 
Check here whether your M2_HOME set correctly